# tracking branch relations with Git

Tags: programming-practices, git, workflows

here is my workflow.
I have master as the most complete version of the program. If I want to add a feature I'll create a branch named with -feat as a suffix. as bugs come up, I'll create new branches from the feature with a -bug suffix. as bugs get solved they get merged back into the parent feature. If the feature branch has no bugs it can be merged back into master.

The problem is how do I track how branches are related. There doesn't seem to be a command to tell me what the last forked branch was. I also want to know what bug branches belong to a feature. (If it has no bugs it can be merged to master)

I could add a note in the commit log. forked from .... However I think this would cause it's own complications.

Comment: What are you using this for? Do you want a 'give me all the branches from master' type report?  Note that you're probably looking for [show-branch](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-show-branch).  You might want to flag this for migration (or delete and repost) to Stack Overflow (see [Where does my git question go?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6311/40980)). I believe that the answer to this is more of a 'tool use' than a 'concept' aspect.

Comment: Have you tried using one of the various Git UIs (e.g. GitUp)?

Comment: I'm not sure I can really explain it better. when you come up with a feature you write some code, it's untested so you put it in a seperate branch. As you test it, Issues come up so you create a branch for that issue. The branch contains code to expose the problem. you can then leave it and work on other things. When you come back to the feature branch if there are no bugs related to the feature then you can merge it with master.

Comment: show-branches seems like it requires you to know which branches are related to use them in the command, which defeats the purpose.